# Dotnet Core 3.1 Kestrel Web API BadRequest, System.NotSupportedException

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, kestrel-http-server

In my server, I have a function like this

```
[HttpPost()]
public void Hello([FromBody]int Version)
{
}
```

I was able to invoke the above API if I omit the **[FromBody]int Version** parameters

```
var c = new HttpClient();
var Json = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Version = 123}), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
var Resp = Api.PostAsync("http://MyURL", Json).Result;
```

If **[FromBody]int Version** is included. I get the following error:

```
Request.Body
{Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpRequestStream}
    CanRead: true
    CanSeek: false
    CanTimeout: false
    CanWrite: false
    Length: '((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpRequestStream)Request.Body).Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
    Position: '((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpRequestStream)Request.Body).Position' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
    ReadTimeout: 'Request.Body.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    WriteTimeout: '((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpRequestStream)Request.Body).WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the answer, in dotnet core 3.x.

1. use **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson** instead of **NewtonsoftJson**
2. Add **services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();**

as pointed out in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#jsonnet-support